# Choosing a Select Menu item and submitting with JQuery

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, translate

I am creating a dropdown of multiple languages that are intended to be a replacement of the ugly google translate dropdown.

My goal is to allow the user to select an item from the dropdown, change the value of the google translate menu selected item to that of the item that was clicked. (if that doesnt make sense, read on, it will!)

My problem is then submitting the translate select menu.

You can see a demo here:  http://bajdesign.com/test

As you can see, when you press language, the dropdown appears, and when you choose an item, you will see that item appear in the google translate dropdown to the left. I need to be able to SUBMIT this translate select menu, but I am unsure how to.

My JQuery is

```
$("#language li a").on("click", function(){
    var thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $(".goog-te-combo").val(thisClass);
});
```

Because the select menu is not contained within a form, I cannot use JQuery `submit()` so what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Then you can go with an Ajax Reuest

Answer (score 0):

How about using an **Ajax Request**...

```
$("#language li a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $(".goog-te-combo").val(thisClass);

    $.ajax({
       type : 'POST',
       url : 'yoururl',
       dataType : 'html',
       data : {"lang" : $(this).attr("class") },
       success : function(result) {
         // Populate your page here
      }
    })
});
```

**Edit**

If thats in a form then you can submit

```
$("#language li a").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $(".goog-te-combo").val(thisClass).submit();
});
```

Comment: THanks, I just implemented this but the ajax is not functioning, most likely because I have not created anything within the success function. What exactly is the ajax request doing here? Im trying to understand so I can put something in the success function.

Comment: You are requesting the data from the server here.. The request is sent to the url specified  , the data attribute holds the data to be sent .. You process the info on the server.,.. Send it back to the client and in the success callback you populate the page with new data  .. For more info check this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: For the URL, am I using the URL of the current page, or the URL that google uses for the translate service? The success function wouldn't be of much help to me, because google converts the html to a different language. I am more or less looking to simply emulate the user choosing a language from the google translate select menu, but rather do it on a home-made menu.

Comment: You need to use the url where the current page is being translated.. How is the html sent back from google translator

Comment: yes, I dont think your mehtod is possible without using the API. I am just trying to do some jQuery trickery by creating another menu and on click, trying to submit the google translate form. You can see here:  http://bajdesign.com/test/

Comment: any alternate ideas besides using an ajax request?

Comment: have you taken a look at the demo? .goog-te-combo is not a form, but a select menu. It is not within a form, so this method will not work. I just updated the demo, you can take a look.

Comment: oops.. I missed that .. How about invoking the same change of the google select .. I believe the translation is done when a selection is changed right.. So that might be in the script file of the translator..

Comment: Yes! That is what I am looking for - to invoke the same change that google's select menu does...but I cannot figure out what change that is...The script file is compressed. Located here: http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js  any ideas?